# drupal doesnt show changes of page.tpl

Tags: drupal

I added a marquee to0 my page.tpl and then deleted it.but website shows it yet. I cleared cash a lot of time but it doesn't work and show the marquee yet in Content section.
could any body help me?
address is:
www.arasac.ir

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell us how did you add it. Because i can see it in a region. Did you do it by adding it to a "Context" or just editted the page.tpl

Answer (score 0):

I added to page.tpl.I cleared cash but it shows yet
you can see it under slide show